# Vercel host to mulitple environmnets like development and qa

Tags: reactjs, next.js, netlify, vercel

I am new to vercel hosting and I play around it with today.
So far what I understand is vercel has two environments by default

1. **production** points to `main` branch
2. **preview** doesn't point to any branch builds on every git repo update

What I want to achieve is I want an environment called development which is points to `DEV` branch.

Another environment is called QA which is pointed to `QA` branch.

I do I achieve this with vercel?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this should be doable with a staging domain.

See the following guide: https://vercel.com/support/articles/set-up-a-staging-environment-on-vercel